# SQS Consumer in loop

Tags: node.js, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS consumer running in Fargate Environment that is triggered from lambda based on SQS queue depth. I want the consumer to run until the messages are parsed and close once the queue is empty. Currently, the consumer is running in a while loop with a retry count. Is there a better way to implement the logic?

Here is my code:

```
const SQS = require("aws-sdk/clients/sqs");
const sleep = require("util").promisify(setTimeout);

const sqs = new SQS({ region: "us-east-1" });

(async () => {
  let retry = 5;
  while (retry >= 0) {
    try {
      let response = await sqs
        .receiveMessage({
          QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL,
          WaitTimeSeconds: 20,
          VisibilityTimeout: 60
        })
        .promise();
      if (response.Messages) {
        retry = retry; /* Reset the retry */
        response.Messages.forEach(async (msg) => {
          /* ------- */
          
          // processing logic

          /* ------- */
          await sqs.deleteMessage({
            QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL,
            ReceiptHandle: msg.ReceiptHandle,
          });
        });
      } else {
        retry = retry - 1;
        console.log("queue is empty");
        if (retry == 0) {
          console.log("Shutting down container.");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    await sleep(1000);
  }
})();
```

Comment: You can use AWS Event Bridge (Preferred now days) or AWS Cloud Watch Event Rule to trigger AWS ECS Task. You can refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html) document. Please read Note from the document also. Instead of AWS S3 from document, you just need to map it to AWS SQS event in your case.

Comment: Thanks, @amitd. Yes, I am AWS Cloud Watch Event Rule to autoscale my Fargate container. My question is more on the consumer code that I am using.